# Externalizing properties files - Widlfly & Struts 1.x

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization, wildfly, web-deployment

I'm working on struts 2.x application and i have a specific requirement to externalize the properties files out of the EAR and put somewhere in file system, in this application i have 2 types of properties files.

Type 1: the files i use at back end level (java code level) and i found a solution for this.

Type 2: the i18n files, **applicationResources_en.properties** file for example used directly by jsp files in order to load a property and with this type of files that i'm having issues with.

```
<bean:message key="api.application.title.display" />
```

The whole application uses the same mechanism for multi language support in its jsp pages, and i haven't found an answer so far to be able to externalize them out of the war.

Any help will be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: You say Struts 2, but you show a Struts 1 tag; which is it? If it's Struts 2 like you say, then https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Can+I+add+I18N+outside+the+Action%27s+context is sufficient to get you started. If it's Struts 1, which you show, IIRC you'd need a custom resource handler.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, it's a struts 1.x. I didn't understand your point.